# sample from two unique categories in R

Tags: r, dplyr, sampling, resampling, categorization

I have 100 unique IDs and 8 unique weeks. I want to sample such that I want one sample with unique ID and unique week. For example ID 1 was sampled 8 times at each week ID 2 was sampled 8 times and so on. I thus have now 800 rows.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sample by group using the sample\_n function of dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995851/sample-by-group-using-the-sample-n-function-of-dplyr)

Answer (score 1):

`df %>% group_bt(ID, category) %>% sample_n(1)` will sample one row from each unique ID:category combination.